# The Server returned unexpected error 1622 attempting to install the.msi file install package

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, spss

When you install the SPSS software, click the exe file and decompress it. "Server returned unexpected error 1622 attempting to
install package
C:\TMP\TMP{8167E4E6-B46E-4D7F-AF1A-A64E15853
6C9} \IBM SPSS Statistics 25.msi.

I tried to turn off the firewall and virus protection and start the Windows Installer, but it still failed. There was no error when installing on another computer. It should be my computer